# Hyperlink display image in ASP.NET Datalist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datalist

I am trying to get an image to display on a page using a Hyperlink inside a datalist.However, the image will not display, I just get the correct number of boxes with what I call the no image picture. I know that it is retrieving the filepath correctly. The tooltip shows the correct path, it is the exact path going into a repeater that works, but does not display the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HomePagePhotosList.ascx.cs"     Inherits="UserControls_HomePagePhotosList" %>
<asp:DataList ID="list" runat="server" Width="1000px" CssClass="EventsList" 
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="DepartmentsListHead" />
   <HeaderTemplate>
   </HeaderTemplate>  
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HyperLink 
      ID="HyperLink1" 
      Runat="server" 
      ImageUrl='<%#System.String.Format("Images/{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Filepath")) %>'
      NavigateUrl='<%# Link.ToEditMinutesAdmin(Eval("ImageID").ToString())%>'
      ToolTip='<%# System.String.Format("Images/{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Filepath")) %>'>
   </asp:HyperLink>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Can you include an example path

Comment: I tried this and it works, so the approach is ok. There must be something that interferes.. Can you take off all css styles just to make sure nothing is being hidden due to dimensions etc

Comment: I took all of the styling out and even dropped it into a freshly created page with no styling at all and still got the no image pic.

Comment: Pls check page source of that iMage control then may be you get idea ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this problem I had to change the

```
ImageUrl='<%#System.String.Format("Images/{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Filepath")) %>'
```

To

```
      ImageUrl='<%#System.String.Format("~/Images/{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Filepath")) %>'
```